# I can't decipher my list

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
list1 = ['o', 'k', 'q', 'a', 'j', 'd']
```

I need to change middle letter to one which corresponds to result of division of 'o' + 'q'.
It means that I use `result == ord('o') + ord('q')` and then divide it by two. And then do this: `chr(result)` and then I paste this letter between 'o' and 'q'.
So in the end it will look like this:
`list1 = ['o', 'p', 'q', 'a', 'c', 'd']`.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly that you are facing? The diving part, the converting part, or the replacing part?

Comment: great plan. go ahead :)

Comment: I can't decipher this question.

Comment: Where did that `c` come from?

Comment: I don't know the replacing part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated how you got `c`. So I assume you automatically get `c`

Try this:

```
list1 = ['o', 'k', 'q', 'a', 'j', 'd']
result = [chr((ord('o') + ord('q'))/2),'c']
list1[1] = result[0]
list1[4] = result[1]
print list1
```

Output:

```
['o', 'p', 'q', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Thanks, that will help me a lot, but I've changed my cipher.

Comment: @RainTenno see now. but next time please avoid changing the question substantially

Comment: Ok, but I still have a question. What code do I need to use if this cipher is v-e-e-ry long? + I need to get c the same way as p(by summing a and d and then dividing by 2)

Comment: @RainTenno You have to start thinking for yourself because in the field there'd be no one to help you. So as a start analyze how this script works and try to extend it...